# Simple anchor tag making double GET request in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, get, anchor

I have a strange problem that some of the other double request questions failed to answer. I have a super simple application that is basically a comic book. Whenever I click the link to go to page two, my server logs two GET requests. I dont remember this always happening. Any ideas what could be causing the duplicate GET requests?

ROUTES.rb

```
root to: 'episodes#index'
resources :episodes, :only => [:index]
post 'pusher/auth'
match '/episodes/:page', to: 'episodes#index', via: 'get'
```

INDEX.HTML.ERB

```
<a id="ep-link-2" href="/episodes/2">&nbsp2&nbsp</a>
```

EPISODESCONTROLLER.RB

```
def index
    @current_episode = params[:page].to_i || 1

    ep_folder = Dir.new("app/assets/images/episodes")
    #returns 0 if folder name is not a number, meaning it's not an actual episode
    ep_folder = ep_folder.reject { |file| file.to_i == 0 }

    @total_episodes = ep_folder.count

    ip = request.remote_ip
    Visitor.has_visited?(ip)

    total_site_visits = Visitor.total_site_visits
    total_uniques = Visitor.total_uniques

    data = {:total_site_visits => total_site_visits,
           :unique_visits => total_uniques }

    @visit_counts = [total_uniques, total_site_visits]


    Pusher['connections'].trigger('new_connection', data)

    @visitor_data = { :total_site_visits => total_site_visits,
                      :unique_visits => total_uniques }


    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :index }
      format.json { render :json => @visitor_data }
    end
  end
```

Comment: Are you using Turbolinks? If you're having Turbolinks track your assets, it might be firing a second get request to reload the head.

Comment: OMG. thank you. i added data-no-turbolink to the links and it worked. yesssss. thank you!

Comment: @jumpReturn do you have Javascript in your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kombo recommended checking out Turbolinks. I added the data-no-turbolink attr to the  and the double request stopped.

Comment: For others this is now data-turbolinks. Reference: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/issues/269